# OS X QuickLook implementation for Collada DAE file?

Tags: macos, quicklook

I'm currently developing a QuickLook generator that will convert an existing file into a 3D Collada DAE format which is supported by QuickLook out of the book and can be zoomed/panned around directly in QuickLook window.
I have looked over the [Apple QuickLook document](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/Quicklook_Programming_Guide/Articles/QLDynamicGeneration.html) which even mentioned that if you convert a document representing a 3D model into Collada DAE format, Quick Look can display a preview interface allowing the model to be zoomed and rotated.

However, what I came across is that the part where I need to pass the data to QuickLook requires a content type UTI in third argument, as provided in the documentation. (In this case, the type is RTF)

```
QLPreviewRequestSetDataRepresentation(preview,
                                      (__bridge CFDataRef)rtfData,
                                      kUTTypeRTF,
                                      NULL);
```

However, I have no idea what to do to display DAE file. What is its UTI ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To determine the UTI of any file on OS X, you can launch `mdls path/to/file` in the Terminal. One of the attributes is `kMDItemContentType`. This is the UTI of the file. For a Collada file this returns:

```
kMDItemContentType             = "org.khronos.collada.digital-asset-exchange"
```

So you can use `CFSTR("org.khronos.collada.digital-asset-exchange")` as the argument you're looking for (there is no pre-defined constant for it).

Comment: How does this answer the question? The op is asking what to use for the third argument, which is `kUTType`

Comment: Updated answer to clarify.